# How to renew letsencrypt cert in AWS Load Balancer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

I used [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate SSL Cert with standalone option, then I generated successfully a SSL cert.

I went to the AWS Load Balancer to config a listener at port 433 and used the SSL cert that I generated before to import at this kind of popup:

[image]

Then everything worked, now I want to renew this SSL cert. I followed this [instruction](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) to renew my cert.

I tried:

**./certbot-auto renew --standalone**

```
=> Checking for new version...
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
   /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt renew --standalone
No renewals were attempted.
```

Or obtain the cert again **./certbot-auto certonly --standalone**

```
Failed authorization procedure. www.atoha.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge. Requested ef39667c9d782884f8157f30f3e85e81.fb4436208f9bc7c8bdeb19356bb090f2.acme.invalid from 54.179.140.152:443. Received certificate containing 'www.my_domain.com'

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.my_domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for TLS-SNI-01 challenge.
   Requested ef39667c9d782884f8157f30f3e85e81.fb4436208f9bc7c8bdeb1935
   6bb090f2.acme.invalid from 54.179.140.152:443. Received certificate
   containing 'www.my_domain.com'

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

This means my cert was generated correctly before, for now I want to know **how to renew it**, since it is nearly expired!

Thanks!

Comment: did you try with `--force-renew` option to force renewable of certificate ?

Comment: Yes, but no result

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

`bash /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto -t --renew-by-default --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly --agree-tos --email 'your@email.com' --webroot --webroot-path 'yourwebdirectory_publichtml' -d yourdomain.com -d www.yourdomain.com`

where `/opt/letsencrypt/` = your letsencrypt directory location

and then place (copy paste) the file's content of .pem to your aws elb (i usually use cat in linux) :

- private key ---> privkey.pem
- public key certificate ---> fullchain.pem
- certificate chain ---> no need to fill this

Comment: I have setup my letsencrypt certs to autorenew via a cronjob in my target servers. When they renew, do I have to reupload the renewed certs to the ELB? Or will the originals just last longer?

Comment: i'm sorry for very late reply, 
my answer above is for manually copy paste the .pem to elb,
if you want to auto upload it, maybe you can try this https://gist.github.com/tobiasmcnulty/f1465b124e34a9dd6872a2f23e314a83, 
but i didn't try it yet

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/alex/letsencrypt-aws to automatically handle automatic renewal on AWS. The only thing it doesn't currently do is remove old certs.

Comment: Currently, it seems the project is no longer maintained: [Note: letsencrypt-aws is not well maintained at this point](https://github.com/alex/letsencrypt-aws/commit/30a72b1ab4223d41dc76f579f6b65f8ae9b6aa1f)